# Is there a per-test non-specific mock reset pattern using Scala+PlaySpec+Mockito?

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scalatest

I'm writing a unit test suite for a Scala Play application and I'm wondering if there's anything analogous to java's

```
@Mock
private Foo foo;

@Autowired/InjectMocks
private Bar fixture;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

For auto-mocking the annotated class and resetting it after every test

Currently I'm settling for

```
TestClass extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterEach

private val foo = mock[Foo]

override def fakeApplication(): Application = 
  new GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[Foo].toInstance(foo)).build

override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
  reset(foo)
}
```

A cursory attempt at using the java annotations in the scala test was not successful. My current approach *works*, I just want to make sure there's not a nicer one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) solves this problem from version 0.1.1, as it provides a trait (`org.mockito.integrations.scalatest.ResetMocksAfterEachTest`) that helps to automatically reset any existent mock after each test is run

The trait has to be mixed **after** `org.mockito.MockitoSugar` in order to work, otherwise your test will not compile

So your code would look like this

```
TestClass extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar with ResetMocksAfterEachTest

private val foo = mock[Foo]

override def fakeApplication(): Application = 
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[Foo].toInstance(foo)).build
```

The main advantage being not having to remember to manually reset each one of the mocks...

If for some reason you want to have a mock that is not reset automatically while using this trait, then it should be 
created via the companion object of `org.mockito.MockitoSugar` so is not tracked by this mechanism

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of that library

Comment: quick attempt at implementation yielded `Error:(29, 44) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method mock in trait ResetMocksAfterEachTest of type (implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Foo], implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Foo])Foo
and  method mock in trait MockitoSugar of type (implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Foo])Foo
match expected type ?
  private val foo = mock[Foo]`

Comment: Are you using `org.mockito.MockitoSugar` or `org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar`?

Comment: the scalatest version

Comment: That's the problem then! Use `org.mockito.MockitoSugar with org.mockito.integrations.scalatest.ResetMocksAfterEachTest` and it will do the trick

Comment: @Bruno is ResetMocksAfterEachTest play well with AsyncFlatSpec? I tried to mix both and it seems to skip my tests

Comment: @NI6 good point, it doesn't, in a couple of hours you'll find v1.11.0 which includes `ResetMocksAfterEachAsyncTest` for those kind of tests